# I am getting the last letter of the word and not getting last column when trying to count number of each type in a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

```
dataset = [
    ['Rainy', 'Windy', 'Cold', 'No'],
    ['Rainy', 'Windless', 'Warm', 'Yes'],
    ['Rainy', 'Windless', 'Cold', 'No'],
    ['Sunny', 'Windy', 'Cold', 'Yes'],
    ['Sunny', 'Windless', 'Warm', 'Yes'],
    ['Sunny', 'Windy', 'Warm', 'Yes'],
    ['Rainy', 'Windy', 'Warm', 'Yes'],
    ['Snow', 'Windy', 'Cold', 'No'],
    ['Snow', 'Windless', 'Cold', 'Yes'],
    ['Snow', 'Windy', 'Cold', 'No'],
    ['Rainy', 'Windy', 'Cold', 'No'],
    ['Sunny', 'Windy', 'Cold', 'Yes'],
    ['Cloudy', 'Windy', 'Cold', 'No'],
    ['Cloudy', 'Windless', 'Cold', 'Yes'],
    ['Cloudy', 'Windy', 'Warm', 'Yes'],
    ['Cloudy', 'Windless', 'Warm', 'Yes'],
]

header = ['Weather', 'Wind', 'Temperature', 'Label']
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns=header)
```

This is my dataset read into pandas.
I am trying to get output of how many times for example every value in each column is counted.

This is the code I have tried and followed a tutorial to get what I want:

```
def count_labels(rows):
    """Counts number of each label in the dataset."""
    counts = {}
    for row in rows:
        label = row[-1]
        if label not in counts:
            counts[label] = 0
        counts[label] += 1
    return counts


print(count_labels(df['Temperature']))
```

I want to get output like: Cold: 10 Warm: 6
but I get this: [image]

Comment: In your function `row` is a word like `Cold`. You don't need to use `label = row[-1]`— that's why you are getting only the last letter. When you write a function, make sure you know the values of all the variables, you can try printing them if you don't.

Comment: Right... Thanks! That solved it.

Comment: Rather than all that manual work, why not `df['Temperature'].value_counts()`? (possibly with `to_dict()`)

Comment: Im following this guide to make a decision tree from scratch. Completely new to both Python and machine learning, so just doing step by step not to screw up somewhere along the way!

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).